# Enqueueing scripts for use within a tinyMCE plugin in Wordpress

Tags: tinymce, wordpress

I have a tinyMCE plugin (for the post/page editor) that I am loading from my Wordpress plugin that needs to have several external javascript files loaded in order for my tinyMCE plugin to work.

In Wordpress 3.3.1 I can just register and enqueue the scripts from the `mce_external_plugins` filter but any Wordpress version below that doesn't load the scripts.

Anybody have experience in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that I found to work with my problem is by hooking to `after_wp_tiny_mce` and then in the callback, calling `wp_print_scripts` directly. It still handles all the dependencies of the scripts.

Also, because `wp_localize_script` won't work with this method due to the scripts not being enqueued, I am echoing my objects directly above my calls to `wp_print_scripts` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var MyLocalizedData = {"foo": "barito"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

**EDIT :**
This fix will only work in Wordpress >= 3.2